# How many solutions are there for this equation: $(x^2-x-1)^{x^2}=(x^2-x-1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My books says the possible solutions to $\hspace{0.2cm}$$(x^2-x-1)^{x^2}=(x^2-x-1)$  $\hspace{0.2cm}$in  $\hspace{0.1cm}$$\mathbb{R}$ $\hspace{0.1cm}$ are $\hspace{0.1cm}$ $-1,1,2$

Is not $\hspace{0.2cm}$ $\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$ $\hspace{0.2cm}$ also a possible solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plugging in the roots of $x^2-x-1$ yields $0^a=0$, which is true as long as $a\ne0$.  Since neither of the roots of $x^2-x-1$ are also roots of $x^2$, they both satisfy the equation.

Answer (score 2):

If $\displaystyle x^2-x-1=0, x=\cdots$

Else $\displaystyle(x^2-x-1)^{(x^2-1)}=1$

Now $\displaystyle a^m=1\implies$

either $m=0, a\ne0$

or $a=1$

or $a=-1,m$ even

Answer (score 1):

Yes, also the roots of $x^2 - x -1$ are solution of this equation